# bash: iterate over array of integers and avoid a value

Tags: bash, list, shell, for-loop

I'd like to do this in a shell script:

```
valueToAvoid = [1, 5, 30]
for i in alist
  if i not in valuesToAvoid then
    doSomething
  endif
endfor
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What exactly? I think you forgot something ;)

Comment: Is every value in alist unique?

Comment: Yes. There cannot be any duplicate in "alist"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have bash4, you can put your forbidden values in an associative array:

```
declare -A avoid
for val in 1 5 30; do avoid[$val]=1; done

for val in {0..99}; do
  if ! [[ ${avoid[$val]} ]]; then
    # Whatever
  fi
done
```

Another alternative is to scan the values to be avoided using, for example, grep. This is probably less efficient but it doesn't require bash 4 features:

```
avoid=(this that "the other")
# Avoided values, one per line. I could have done this with a here-doc,
# but sometimes it's useful to convert an array to a sequence of lines
avoid_lines=$(printf %s\\n "${avoid[@]}")

for val in one "the other" two; do
  if ! grep -qFx -e"$val" <<<"$avoid_lines"; then
    # Whatever
  fi
done
```

Comment: @deadbird. Oops, sorry. Fixed.

Comment: Here's my script, based on what you gave me (sorry, had trouble formatting it here): http://pastebin.com/mjEfWXVz

The "echo" line is never displayed, can you point my error out?

Comment: @deadbird: if you have a sufficiently recent bash, you can use `[[ -v avoid[$val] ]]` (which is what I had originally), but that doesn't work with bash 4.2. I did the edit in a hurry :(

Comment: @deadbird: Precisely. That's why I removed the suggestion.